# Adding Button to change value

Tags: javascript, html, css, setinterval, init

i'm working on an assignment and have followed tutorials to build a snake game. I wish to change the speed of the game value 100 by using 2 buttons one for increasing the value and another one to decrease the value 100..

```
//To move the snake
//every 100ms
if(typeof game_loop != "undefined") clearInterval(game_loop);
    game_loop = setInterval(paint, 100);
}
init();
```

Thank you.

Comment: What did you tried so far ?

Comment: Please give more details on how your whole speed implementation is done and where exactly your problem lies

Answer (score 1):

Change the 100 to a global variable.

```
var refresh = 100;
```

and substitute the 100 in the setInterval for your new variable

```
setInterval(paint, refresh);
```

create two html buttons

```
<button id="button_faster">Faster</button>
<button id="button_slower">Slower</button>
```

then some javascript/jquery to make the button alter the refresh speed

```
$("#button_faster").on("click", function(){
    if(refresh > 0) refresh -= 10;
});

$("#button_slower").on("click", function(){
        if(refresh < 10000) refresh += 10;
    });
```

I put in place limits for the speed but those don't have to be there.